# Process Hollowing and Kernel

Tags: malware, process

I still do not fully understand how process hollowing works.
I know how to do it and understand every step in using it.

But why does the system still see the process as the "host" process and not the target process at the end, even if we change in the code the PEB to the PEB of the target process?

Does the kernel save it somewhere?

Comment: What os are we talking about? What does your code do? To answer your question, we'd need to be able to read your mind.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - process howling is a generic name for a technique where an inconspicuous piece of malware starts a process under one name (a name that an AV will consider safe) and then substitutes that process' memory with the malware code.  On the other hand, i'm a little confused about what OP means with "PEB".

Comment: And I'm confused about him using "the kernel", which implies a *specific* OS... But I have not a single clue about what PEB should be, either

Comment: A [Google Search](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=process+hollowing+windows) brought up two useful docs. [Analyzing Malware Hollow Processes](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Analyzing-Malware-Hollow-Processes/) and [Process Hollowing](http://www.autosectools.com/process-hollowing.pdf).

Comment: ok i will try explain,i used this code-http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40262-dynamic-forking-process-hollowing/  and it all works and i understand how it works-but what i dont understand is what part of the OS "detected" the process? is there some kind of a table or maybe an object that is being saved in the kernel?

Answer (score 2):

That would most likely be the Virtual address descriptor (VAD).  More information about Process Hollowing techniques can be found at https://cysinfo.com/detecting-deceptive-hollowing-techniques/